# Prove these statements with A-measurable functions are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(Ω,A,μ)$ be a measure space with finite measure $μ$. Let $f, f_n : Ω →\mathbb{R}$
be $A$-measurable functions ($n∈\mathbb{N}$). Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

1) For every $ε > 0$,

$lim_{n→∞}μ(\bigcup\limits_{m>=n}{x ∈ Ω:f_m(x) > f (x) + ε})=0$

2) For every $δ > 0$ there exists $B_δ∈A$ with $μ(B_δ)<δ$ such that for every $ε > 0$ there exists $N_ε ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x) <= f (x) + ε$ for all $x ∈ Ω\setminus A_δ$ and $n>=N_ε$.

So, I started with the fact that (1) is also equivalent to the statement that for every $ε > 0$ and $δ > 0$ there exists an $B_{δ,ε}∈A$ with $μ(B_{δ,ε})<δ$ and a $N_{δ,ε} ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x) <= f (x) + ε$ for all $n>=N_{δ,ε}$ and $x∈B_{δ,ε}^\complement$. But I don't know how to continue.